# Spring Jpa @Transactional not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to achieve transaction roll back if one or more queries fail. so i annotated `@Transactional` on my service implementation class. I knowingly sent wrong data type amountpaid1 (String in this case, Double is correct data type).

But now, my first update query plus insertion on challan completes successfully.
 Second query i.e query1 fails to update as it receives wrong data type so i expect the whole transaction to roll back.

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public class UpdatePaymentImpl implements UpdatePayment {


@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public PaymentResponse getFcgoApiResponse(FcgoUpdateParam updateParam){
    PaymentResponse paymentResponse = new PaymentResponse();
    try {
        final String uri = "http://a.b.c.d:xxxx/FcgoApi/api/savePayment";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        paymentResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, updateParam, 
        PaymentResponse.class);
            if (paymentResponse.getVoucherNo() != null) {
                int status = updatePayment(updateParam, 
                paymentResponse.getVoucherNo());
                if (status == 0) {
                    vc.setVoucherNo(paymentResponse.getVoucherNo());
                }
            }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.info(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return paymentResponse;

}


    @Transactional
    public int updatePayment(FcgoUpdateParam updateParam, String voucherno){

        try{
            String amountPaid1 = updateParam.getAmountPaid();
            Double amountPaid=Double.parseDouble(updateParam.getAmountPaid());
            String masterId= updateParam.getMasterId();
            String advCode=updateParam.getAdvCode();
            long uuid = getUniqueID();
            logger.info("generated uuid "+uuid);
            DateFormat dateFormat =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy h.mm.ss.000000000 a");
            SimpleDateFormat dms = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String cdate = updateParam.getChallanDate();
            Date ddate= dms.parse(cdate);
            String challandate = dateFormat.format(ddate);
            String office = updateParam.getOffice();
            String username = updateParam.getUsername();
            Long id = getIdOnChallanTable()+1L;

            String challanid = String.valueOf(uuid);
            ChallanEntity challanEntity = new ChallanEntity();
            challanEntity.setAdvtcode(updateParam.getAdvCode());
            challanEntity.setAmount(amountPaid);
            challanEntity.setName(updateParam.getName());
            challanEntity.setOffice(office);
            challanEntity.setUsername(username);
            challanEntity.setStatus(updateParam.getStatus());
            challanEntity.setChallandate(challandate);
            challanEntity.setChallanid(uuid);
            challanEntity.setChallantime("null");
            challanEntity.setVoucherno(voucher no);
            Query query= em.createQuery("update 
            CandidateappearagainstadvtcodeEntity cd set 
     cd.paymentstatus='Completed',cd.amountpaid=:depoFee,cd.challanid=:challanid
             where cd.studentmasterid=:masterid and cd.advertisementcode=:advCode");
            logger.info("update parameter advt code: "+updateParam.getAdvCode());
            query.setParameter("depoFee",updateParam.getAmountPaid());
            query.setParameter("challanid",challanid);
            query.setParameter("masterid",masterId);
            query.setParameter("advCode",advCode)
            .executeUpdate();
            Query query1 =em.createQuery(" update CandidateappeartoadvtnumberEntity 
            cnd set cnd.paymentstatus='Completed', cnd.depositedfee=:depofee where
            cnd.studentmasterid=:masterid and cnd.advertisementcode=:advcode");
            String masterId1= updateParam.getMasterId();
            String advCode1=updateParam.getAdvCode();

            query1.setParameter("depofee",amountPaid1);
            query1.setParameter("masterid",masterId1);
            query1.setParameter("advcode",advCode1)
            .executeUpdate();

            em.persist(challanEntity);
            em.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            logger.info("update error " +e);
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
            return 0;

        }
        return 1 ;
    }

    }
```

**Service Class**

```
    @Service
    public class UpdatePaymentServiceImpl implements UpdatePaymentService {

    @Autowired
    UpdatePayment updatePayment;

    @Transactional
    public PaymentResponse getFcgoApiResponse(FcgoUpdateParam updateParam) {
        return updatePayment.getFcgoApiResponse(updateParam);
    }

    }
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.
    orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.psc" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" 
        ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Transactions will roll back in the event of an exception being thrown from the Transactional method.

Rollback for a runtime exception is automatic.

Rollback for checked exceptions needs to be explicitly configured.

Your Transactional method never throws an Exception as you catch all exceptions within it. So you either need to throw or rethrow from within the catch block.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = MyCustomException.class) // << 
public int updatePayment(FcgoUpdateParam updateParam, String voucherno) 
    throws Exception{

    int a = 5/0; unhandled runtime exception : transaction rolls back

    try{
            //runtime exception is caught and never rethrown - no rollback
            int a = 5/0; 
    }
    catch (Exception e){
            // exception in try block re-thrown: transaction rolls back
            // throw(e); 
    }

    throw new MyCustomException(); //checked exception rollback only occurs if configured  

    return 1 ;
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back

> **The recommended way to indicate to the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure that a transaction’s work is to be rolled
>   back is to throw an Exception from code that is currently executing in
>   the context of a transaction.** The Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure code will catch any unhandled Exception as it bubbles
>   up the call stack, and make a determination whether to mark the
>   transaction for rollback.
>
> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case
>   of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception
>   is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. ( Errors will also -
>   by default - result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are thrown
>   from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default
>   configuration.